# complete nub is making a jquery custom banner with fade fx. run for your life

Tags: jquery, menu, fadein, flicker, banner

here is it:
http://www.exhibitiondesign.com/include/jquery/jquery.banner.1.0.html

i'd say im nearly there, the flickering is the main issue - and i know the problem is the fades are being triggered whenever links are being hovered on/off. i just dont know how to implement either a visibility check, or another way of creating the same effect.
i also have some flawed logic on the services: design > content hovering, 'design' should remain for both the services children.
at the end of it all, i want to encapsulate the entire thing into a .js, the html code too with document.write.
any help would be appreciated, i'm no coder, and js i've only been looking at for a few weeks so i'd need lamens terms. here is the relevant css, html and js:

```
    #banner{width:100%; height:40px; background:#000;}
    #banner ul{width:1024px; margin:auto; padding:0; list-style:none;}
    #banner ul li{height:16px; margin:10px 40px 0 0; float:left;}
    #banner ul li a{font-size:9pt; color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;}
    .line1a,.line1b,.line1c,.line1d,.line1e,.line1f{display:none;}
    .line2a,.line2b,.line2c,.line2d,.line2e,.line2f{display:none;}
    .companyname{font-size:16pt; color:#FFF; width:220px; margin:7px 0; float:right;}


<div id="banner">
  <ul>
   <li class="line1a">
    <a href="/home/home.html">HOME</a>
   </li>
   <li class="line1b">
    <a href="/profile/profile.html">PROFILE</a>
    <div class="line2b">
     <a href="/press/press.html">PRESS</a>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="line1c">
    <a href="/client_directory/client_directory.html">CLIENT DIRECTORY</a>
    <div class="line2c">
     <a href="/testimonials/testimonials.html">TESTIMONIALS</a>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="line1d">
    <a href="/projects/projects.html">PROJECTS</a>
   </li>
   <li class="line1e" style="width:60px;">
    <a href="/services/design.html" class="swap" style="cursor:pointer;">SERVICES</a>
    <div class="line2e">
     <a href="/services/content.html">CONTENT</a>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="line1f" style="width:60px;">
    <a href="/contact/contact.html">CONTACT</a>
    <div class="line2f">
     <a href="/recruitment/recruitment.html">RECRUITMENT</a>
    </div>
   </li>
   <div class="companyname">
    MORRIS ASSOCIATES
   </div>
  </ul>
 </div>




    $(document).ready(function(){

 //remove outline from links
 $("a").click(function(){
  $(this).blur();
 });

 //swap services text
 $(".swap").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).text("DESIGN");
 });
 $(".swap").mouseout(function(){
  $(this).text("SERVICES");
 });

 //when mouse is on banner
 $("#banner").mouseover(function(){
  $("#banner").stop(true, false).animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:200, easing: 'easeInQuad'});
  $(".line1a").stop(true, true).fadeIn(400)
  $(".line1b").stop(true, true).fadeIn(400)
  $(".line1c").stop(true, true).fadeIn(400)
  $(".line1d").stop(true, true).fadeIn(400)
  $(".line1e").stop(true, true).fadeIn(400)
  $(".line1f").stop(true, true).fadeIn(400)
 });

 //when mouse is off banner
 $("#banner").mouseout(function(){
  $("#banner").stop(true, true).animate({height:'40px'},{queue:false, duration:200, easing: 'easeInQuad'});
  $(".line1a").stop(true, true).fadeOut(400)
  $(".line1b").stop(true, true).fadeOut(400)
  $(".line1c").stop(true, true).fadeOut(400)
  $(".line1d").stop(true, true).fadeOut(400)
  $(".line1e").stop(true, true).fadeOut(400)
  $(".line1f").stop(true, true).fadeOut(400)
 });

 //when mouse is on line1
 $(".line1a").mouseover(function(){
  $(".line2a").stop(true, true).fadeIn(400)
 });
 $(".line1b").mouseover(function(){
  $(".line2b").stop(true, true).fadeIn(400)
 });
 $(".line1c").mouseover(function(){
  $(".line2c").stop(true, true).fadeIn(400)
 });
 $(".line1d").mouseover(function(){
  $(".line2d").stop(true, true).fadeIn(400)
 });
 $(".line1e").mouseover(function(){
  $(".line2e").stop(true, true).fadeIn(400)
 });
 $(".line1f").mouseover(function(){
  $(".line2f").stop(true, true).fadeIn(400)
 });

 //when mouse is off line1
 $(".line1a").mouseout(function(){
  $(".line2a").stop(true, true).fadeOut(400)
 });
 $(".line1b").mouseout(function(){
  $(".line2b").stop(true, true).fadeOut(400)
 });
 $(".line1c").mouseout(function(){
  $(".line2c").stop(true, true).fadeOut(400)
 });
 $(".line1d").mouseout(function(){
  $(".line2d").stop(true, true).fadeOut(400)
 });
 $(".line1e").mouseout(function(){
  $(".line2e").stop(true, true).fadeOut(400)
 });
 $(".line1f").mouseout(function(){
  $(".line2f").stop(true, true).fadeOut(400)
 });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take it step by step, first the swap issue.  If you want the text to remain when hovering children too, put it on the parent `<li>` instead of the `<a>`, like this:

```
<li class="line1e swap" style="width:60px;">
 <a href="/services/design.html" style="cursor:pointer;">SERVICES</a>
 <div class="line2e">
  <a href="/services/content.html">CONTENT</a>
 </div>
</li>
```

Then jQuery hovers to match, like this:

```
$(".swap").hover(function(){
  $(this).children("a").text("DESIGN");
}, function(){
  $(this).children("a").text("SERVICES");
});
```

For all the other issues, it's because [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) fire **when entering children**, you're seeing the most common side-effect, flickering with animations.  Instead, use [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)...or the shortcut, [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), like this:

```
$("#banner").hover(function(){
  $("#banner").stop(true, false).animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:200, easing: 'easeInQuad'});
  $(this).find("> ul > li").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
},  function(){
  $("#banner").stop(true, true).animate({height:'40px'},{queue:false, duration:200, easing: 'easeInQuad'});
  $(this).find("> ul > li").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
});

$("#banner > ul > li").hover(function() {
  $(this).children("div").fadeIn();
}, function() {
  $(this).children("div").fadeOut();
});
```

[You can test the result out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5A5Kw/).  Also note that through the use of [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) [relative to `this`](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/), you can avoid all that duplicate code and slim your handlers way down.  You can also remove all those `.lineXX` classes unless they're needed for something else.

Comment: wow nick, thank you so much its perfect. that jsfiddle is also very neat, i shall be using that in the future.

Comment: maybe in the future i can reimburse you by trying to help some others in here; css and html nothing else :{>